# Duplicate Queries in Laravel- Debugger

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update the columns of the records based on the other column records but it results in the duplicate queries since its being executed for each record in the table.I s there a way to avoid it and improve this code.

```
 public function updateReviewColumn(){
        $reviewData = $this->pluck('indicator')->toArray();
        foreach ($reviewData as $datum) {
            if ($datum == 'Y')
                $this->where('indicator', $datum)
                    ->update(['reviewindicator' => 'Yes']);
            else
                $this->where('indicator', $datum)
                    ->update(['reviewindicator' => 'No']);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would transform this following query into a eloquent stmt:

```
UPDATE  yourTable
SET     indicator = IF(indicator = 'Y', 'Yes','No'),    
WHERE   indicator= 'Y' OR indicator= 'N'
```

To have it one shot I think you should go for DB raw query (if you got MySQL behind)

Otherwise you can go for two different Eloquent stmt

```
MyTable::where('indicator', 'Y')->update(['indicator' => 'Yes']);

MyTable::where('indicator', 'N')->update(['indicator' => 'No']);
```

Probably you'll face issues if you got safe_updates enabled in MySQL